# Multiple different toasts I want to check at same time on my page, but my Cypress E2E test only fails on the one it sees first

Tags: cypress, toast

I am using Cypress to check pop up toast messages.  I normally just have 1 single toast, that I can catch and compare with no issues, but when I have multiple toasts at the same time, that are not repeats, but instead each their own message, my test catches only the first one and fails.

example for single toast:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('lookAtToast', (message) => {
  cy.get('.messenger-message-inner').eq(0).should('contain.text', message);
});
```

Can anyone help me with a method in Cypress 12 (latest) to be able to look at all 3 toasts, and be able to match any of them, 1 at a time...in any order.
Ex.  If I have a toast message of "First Toast", then "Second Toast", then "Third Toast"
and I want to be able to have a test that can look at them and match one of them, but not necessarily the first one it sees.

Expected to get 1 and only 1 toast to match with this.

Comment: Are these tests using the same set of credentials each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with toasts is they come and go at different times, even if the gap between is small.

The problem with using `.each()` is `cy.get('.messenger-message-inner')` will move on as soon as it sees the first toast.

But if the 2nd, 3rd, etc are delayed even slightly they will never be caught.

Maybe assert the number of toasts expected, like this

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('lookAtToast', (messages) => {  // array of messages

cy.get('.messenger-message-inner')
  .should('have.length', 3)
  .each((el, index) => {
    cy.wrap(el).should('contain.text', messages[index])
  })
```

---

If there is no strict order to the toasts (you seem to be saying that), then this variation would be better

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('lookAtToast', (messages) => {  // array of messages

cy.get('.messenger-message-inner')
  .should('have.length', 3)
  .each((el, index) => {
    const text = el.text()
    expect(messages.includes(text)).to.eq(true)
  })
```

---

Here's another approach that should work as you describe in comments

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('lookAtToast', (message) => {  // one message

  cy.get('.messenger-message-inner')   
    .then($toasts => [...$toasts].map(toast => toast.innerText))
    .should('include', message)  
})

// trigger toast 1
cy.lookAtToast('toast 1 message')

// trigger toast 2
cy.lookAtToast('toast 2 message')

// trigger toast 3
cy.lookAtToast('toast 3 message')
```

Here we get all the toasts currently showing on the page, convert the elements into the text content, then assert that the message passed in is one of those toast messages.

---

Another way is to make use of the toast message container, depending on how the HTML looks this could work.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('lookAtToast', (message) => {  // one message

  cy.get('.messenger-message-inner')   
    .parent()                      
    .should('contain', message)  
})
```

Here we are saying that the toast parent element has the message somewhere in itself or a child element.

Since `.should('contain', message)` checks all descendants, it will look at every toast for the `message` text.

Comment: The one you listed first works, but I have to know exactly how many toasts are going to show up.  I have situations where 3 or maybe even 4 will show up at once.  When I assume 3, it works great, but would love to get the 2nd one you have listed working to allow me to be able to call this lookAtToast method for all 3 or 4 messages, and each of them match with a toast.  I noticed, that in your second method you never used the index.  Could that be why it isn't working for me?

Comment: Ok, I read above you had 3... what about the messages, do know what they are? Probably not from what you say. Not the best situation to run a test. Why is it so flaky?

Comment: Re the 2nd example not using index - it's not needed because the test is inverted - the check is that the toast is somewhere in the messages (order does not matter, hence index is not needed).

Comment: Ok, I re-read your comment - I think I know what you need now.

Comment: The single test I was looking at had 3, which was the one I wrote about, so when this one worked, I tried the function in another test I have, but noticed the other one had 4.  The 3 toasts include "Successfully saved. Successfully created Draft.  and Successfully created new Version".   I really appreciate your help on the 3!  It works great.

Comment: This last one works So Well!  Thanks you so much Elizabeth!

Comment: Excellent! I think I need a cup of tea now.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each

```
Cypress.Commands.add('lookAtToast', (message) => {
  cy.get('.messenger-message-inner').each((el) => {
    cy.wrap(el).should('contain.text', message);
  });
});
```